# What does "C'est rendu du quotidien pour moi" mean?

Tags: sens

The following are (non-auto-generated) subtitles from the beginning of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfbZqJZBeR4) youtube video. (I've added information to the transcript about who is speaking).

First, we are introduced to a couple who, after three years, finally obtained their permanent residence status:

> *(journalist speaks:)*
>  La neige et le froid sont là pour rester dans la vie de Marco Mariatti. 
> *(husband of the couple speaks:)* 
> J'étais très heureux... Enfin c'est fini, c'est fait! 
> *(journalist:)*
> Andréane Paquet et Marco Mariatti sont ensemble depuis
> 17 ans. Leur histoire d'amour leur a donné trois enfants.
> Après trois ans d'attente, l'Italien d'origine vient enfin
> d'obtenir sa résidence permanente. 
> [....]

Then the journalist explains that the processing of permanent residence applications has been taking a lot longer than normal:

> *(journalist:)*
> La pandémie et l'arrivée des réfugiés afghans a ralenti le
> processus d'immigration de bien des ménages. Des dossiers
> simples, comme le leur, qui devaient se régler en moins
> d'un an, peuvent maintenant prendre entre deux et
> quatre ans, selon cette consultante en immigration.

and then the news broadcast cuts to an Immigration Consultant, who makes a comment on the situation:

> *(immigration consultant:)*
> **C'est rendu du quotidien pour moi.** Chose qu'avant on voyait en
> huit, neuf, douze mois maximum.

---

DeepL translates the bolded sentence into a sentence that doesn't seem make sense to me:

> It's made everyday life easier for me.

If there are many married couples in Québec who are stressed out because their permanent residence applications are being delayed, wouldn't it make an Immigration Consultant's life harder, instead of easier?

---

I tried exploring other possible translations.

Things I observe, first, before trying to find a translation:

- I know that in the passé composé, rendre is conjugated with the auxillary verb being "avoir", not "être", so I know "C'est rendu" is *not* using the passé composé of "rendre".
- the WordReference [page](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/rendre) for rendre does not include a "rendre de" entry, so the "de" in "C'est rendu du [ = **de** + le] quotidien pour moi" is less likely to have an idiomatic meaning, and is more likely to have a more "typical" meaning (eg, perhaps it's a partitive article? or perhaps it's "de" = from? etc).

---

So, here are my attempts at translations:

1. WordReference: **rendre [qch] à [qqn] = (restituer) -> give [sth] back to [sb]**

   - It(/This) gave back some everday-life "pour moi" 
     -> This situation gave me back some everyday life [??],
     or -> This situation gave me back some everyday life, in my opinion (/ in my experience) [??]
2. (Regionalism) : **Être rendu = Être arrivé**

   - It(/This) arrived "du quotidien pour moi" 
     -> It(/This) arrived of the everyday-life "for me" 
     -> *(I can't even massage this into a sentence that makes sense, even if I try..)*

Attempt #1 doesn't make sense; the undesirable delays in processing permanent residence applications is *not* everyday life for the Immigration Consultant, so certainly the Immigration Consultant wasn't given back an everyday life. And #2 I can't make into a workable translation.

So, I'm stuck!

---

Question:

- What does the Immigration Consultant mean when she says "C'est rendu du quotidien pour moi"?

Comment: It's made everyday life easier for me. **That is inaccurate**. It means: That's become a part of daily life for me. "le quotidien" is "daily life". Also: regular thing, colloquially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm French so not from Québec and some subtleties may escape me but I understand that as:

C'est rendu du quotidien => C'est devenu quotidien.

Comment: ha. that would make so much sense. i wish my brain had better linguistic intuition, so that my brain could have guessed that meaning! could you give me some more example sentences with this meaning of "rendre"? and am i right to think that "du" is not a partitive article, but instead it is "rendre de" + "le quotidien"?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a quebecism.

Comment: Yes: [*C'est rendu du n'importe quoi, il est temps qu'il enlève le couvre feu*](https://www.facebook.com/LaPresseFB/posts/10161287259433312?comment_id=10161287393528312); [Être rendu | En être à un certain point, être arrivé à | Vous êtes où ? On est rendu à Montréal ; T'es rendu végétarien maintenant ?](http://vi-et-dav-au-quebec.chez-alice.fr/livrebord/expressions.htm)

Comment: i'm still confused about what "du" is. Why is the "du" in "C'est rendu **du** quotidien" or "C'est redu **du** n'importe quoi" instead not *de*, or even null? is "du quotidien" using "du" as the partitive article, or is it "rendre de + le quotidien"?

Comment: That would be a partitive.  Note that Marco Mariatti speaks with an accent that is a mixture of Canadian French and Italian. With him, the subtitles do a better job than my ears as I would have had a hard time understanding *heureux* (pronounced like "*érose*") and would have confused *fait* with *fête*.

Comment: @jlliagre oh wow, you're right. i wasn't even paying attention to the audio, but it's amazing how different *heureux* can sound compared to any Québecois/Canadian, Acadian, or French accent that i've been hearing as i've learned French!

Answer (score 5):

Ici *rendre* signifie *devenir*.

Le verbe *rendre* a plusieurs sens, dont *faire que quelque chose/quelqu'un devienne …* : par exemple « ce geste l'a rendu célèbre » signifie « ce geste a fait qu'il est devenu célèbre ». Ce sens existe aussi sous forme pronominale : *se rendre* peut signifier *devenir*, par exemple la phrase précédente peut aussi se dire « il s'est rendu célèbre par ce geste ».

Je comprends « c'est rendu … » comme « c'est devenu … ». C'est un sens qui n'existe pas en français standard de France, mais je crois que c'est un régionalisme, et c'est peut-être courant au Québec (à confirmer, je ne l'ai pas trouvé dans des dictionnaires en ligne).

« C'est du quotidien » signifie « cela fait partie de l'expérience quotidienne », autrement dit ce n'est pas exceptionnel, cela arrive couramment, voire c'est ce à quoi on s'attend par défaut. Je vois une différence avec « c'est quotidien » qui dit que cela arrive une fois pas jour. Cela dit, comme « c'est quotidien » peut être une exagération, « c'est quotidien » peut avoir le même sens que « c'est du quotidien ».

Answer (score 1):

Je vois ça comme *c'est devenu monnaie courante* mais je trouve ça difficile à analyser et j'avais pas la perception que c'était régional. *C'est rendu* illustre il me semble un degré différent, un changement d'état ou de position, voire *devenir* (le résultat actuel ou final), tel qu'on l'a déniché en [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/49693/what-does-cest-rendu-du-quotidien-pour-moi-mean#comment102180_49694) (mais j'ai l'impression que ça découle des sens usuels de [*rendre*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rendre)). *Du [quotidien](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quotidien)*, c'est un substantif en attribut de la situation (les normes de délai de traitement des dossiers dans le domaine qui ont changé, c'est plus long), comme un syntagme de classement, une catégorie, *du quotidien, de l'exception, du bleu, du *small** (*petit*, vêtement) etc. On obtient possiblement une valeur similaire à l'adjectif (*quotidien, exceptionnel, bleu, petit*) avec la partie d'un tout.

C'est facile à dire après coup, mais on aurait compris peut-être plus vite en découpant « c'est rendu », et là on attend une précision sur le changement d'état, puis « quotidien » comme dans la [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/49694) et en accordant moins d'importance au déterminant de prime abord. Peut-être que la préposition *dans* avec un possessif aide aussi à élaborer un prototype de phrase pas idiomatique, avec des sens plus concrets, mais utile pour comprendre ce « syntagme » ou emploi partitif (*c'est rendu dans mon quotidien*, courant, éventuellement la nouvelle norme) ; sinon avec la préposition *à* « [au quotidien](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/au_quotidien) » (le quotidien du consultant).

Comment: i'm having a lot of trouble understanding your answer, even with the help of DeepL and a dictionary. a) what do you mean when you suggest cutting "c'est rendu" and "attend une précision sur le changement d'état" ("by waiting for a precision on the change of state" -- what state are you talking about?). b) what do you mean by "en accordant moins d'importance au déterminant"? what determinant? the only determinant i see is "du" in "du quotidien". c) you say that "dans mon quotidien" would help to elaborate what is a "propotype de phrase pas idiomatique"? "a non-idiomatic prototypical sentence"?

Comment: @silph I'm just trying to provide a way to analyze this sort of construction. You were trying to figure out the interplay between the verb and what follows (_du quotiden_). I'm saying when you see "c'est rendu" in a context like this, forget _du_ and focus on the substantive _quotidien_; so I guess I'm saying see it as a set expression, so a preposition won't change what it means down the line. The state I'm talking about is because _c'est rendu_ implies that there was a state before, and a new state. Consider _c'est rendu / qu'il veut manger 5 fois par jour_, so it was less than 5 before this

Comment: _A non-idiomatic prototypical sentence_ is indeed what I mean. Those sentenses are not for using, just for analysis. Using _dans_ or _au_ can help. In Gilles', he refers to _fait partie de_, and I equate that with _dans_ (belongs to, is inside of); _au_ can help because you have that set construct _au quotidien_. I thought those prepositions would be more telling than _de/du_ in context but maybe not. It's not clear that I can think as if I were not a native speaker, which I tried to do here. Maybe I need to reword some of that stuff.

Comment: I guess your attempt _arrived of the everyday-life_ might have influenced me here. That _of_ felt like _origin_ to me (from). I guess if you had used _in_ or _at my_ instead of _of_, you might have gotten closer to the meaning you were looking for and this is want I was trying to hint at. But then again, it's not clear that there is any trick here, you just have to recognize the set property of the _c'est rendu_. But still, _c'est rendu à moi_ just means it's my turn, not clear how my "technique" would help here loll. Ok, it wasn't, now it is.